# Which color palette is used by radio buttons

Tags: angular-material

I am trying to change color of radio button and ink ripple. Overriding individual CSS selectors is painful and error prone. I don't even want to add "md-primary" or "md-accent" classes to my radio buttons across my app. I would like to override default theme. I scavenged documentation and searched Google, SO, Angular Material GitHub and demo page but could not find answer to simple question:

Which color palette of default theme is used by radio buttons?

Answer (score 0):

After a little experiment I figured out that accent palette is used by radio buttons.

There is vague indication at the end on Material Theme introduction page (https://material.angularjs.org/latest/Theming/01_introduction) that states that accent palette is used by "secondary interface elements"; however there is no documentation that states that radio buttons are secondary interface elements.

Update:
API documentation of Radio button mentions that it uses accent color.
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdRadioGroup